# How can I import many binary files in Dask?

Tags: python, dask

I have many binary files (.tdms format, similar to .wav) stored in S3 and I would like to read them with `nptdms` then process them in a distributed fashion with Dask on a cluster.

In PySpark there is `pyspark.SparkContext.binaryFiles()` which produces an RDD with a bytearray for each input file which is a simple solution to this problem.

I have not found an equivalent function in Dask - is there one? If not, how could the equivalent functionality be achieved in Dask?

I noticed there's `dask.bytes.read_bytes()` if it's necessary to involve this however `nptdms` can't read a chunk of a file - it needs the entire file to be available and I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dask.bytes.read_bytes()` will give you whole files if you use `blocksize=None`, i.e., exactly one block per file. The most common use case for that is compressed files (e.g., gzip) where you can't start mid-stream, but should work for your use case too. Note that the delayed objects you get each return *bytes*, not open files.

Alternatively, you can use `fsspec.open_files`. This returns `OpenFile` objects, which are safe to serialise and so you can use them in `dask.delayed` calls such as

```
ofs = fsspec.open_files("s3://...", ...)

@dask.delayed
def read_a_file(of):
    with of as f:
        # entering context actually touches storage
        return TdmsFile.read(f)

tdms = [read_a_file(of) for of in ofs]
```